# Crop Arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

Okey, this seems fairly dumb, but I cannot make it in a clean way:
How shall one crop arrays in Julia, acording to a condition in certain column?
To be more specific, I have a 2D Array, with three columns. The third one is monotonous increasing with the index. So I want to get to get the Subarray that contains all three columns, until the third column reaches certain specified value and no more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an elementwise comparison as an indexer:

```
julia> a = rand(5,3); a[:,3] = cumsum(a[:,3]);

julia> a
5×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.265171   0.338287   0.499986
 0.669729   0.335505   1.42725 
 0.504523   0.0826387  2.40342 
 0.0435413  0.268485   3.35813 
 0.913878   0.751294   3.38864 

julia> a[a[:,3] .< 2.5, :]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.265171  0.338287   0.499986
 0.669729  0.335505   1.42725 
 0.504523  0.0826387  2.40342
```

Comment: Oh, I've never seen such a notation `(A[A[bla, blu] .<something, bla])`... could you explain it in detail?